# "TextInputSequence must be str” error on Hugging Face Transformers

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I’m very new to HuggingFace, I’ve come around this error “**TextInputSequence must be str**” on a notebook which is helping me a lot to do some practice on various hugging face models. **The boilerplate code on the notebook is throwing this error (I guess) due to some changes in huggingface’s API** or something. So I was wondering if someone could suggest some changes that I can make to the code to resolve the error.

***The error can easily be reproduced by just running all the cells of the notebook.***

**Link**: [Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1K9H753cX0tD0lsoXvyHsDhrTtbnzq1bL?usp=sharing&authuser=1#scrollTo=d5YvAzA5QJER)

#### This is the line that is throwing the error-[image: the code throwing error2]

#### Here is the error-[image: error trace]

Comment: [Please never ever upload screenshots of code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thank you for your response, the point of the screenshot wasn't the code though, rather I wanted to help by pointing out the line that's causing the error, for the code I provide the whole notebook. However, if it's something not appropriate, then I'll take that out. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with data , the data consists of None type or other data type except string

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the transformers library not being backwards compatible—you must use 3.4.0. To run this notebook you must do the following steps.

First, make sure you have full hw1 folder and download it locally.

Second issue the follow commands:

```
conda create --name my_env python=3.6
conda install -c conda-forge notebook
jupyter notebook
```

Now, remove all colab related code and download torch.

Lastly, replace the transformers import with the following:

```
!python -m pip install -Iv transformers==3.4.0
```

Then you should be able to run!

Comment: If this works, please remember to mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!